# GeoDjango query raster pixel values in PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, raster, geodjango, django

I am building a REST API in GeoDjango that queries pixel values on a multiband raster held in PostGIS (out of db).

I have defined the following model to match the raster held on the database:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Brt2(models.Model):
    rid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rast = models.RasterField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'brt2'
    managed = False
```

When I try to query the raster model using a point, it's taking around 30 seconds and returning an empty Queryset.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

>> pt = Point(-3.43, 52.946)
>> qs = Brt2.objects.filter(rast__1__contains=pt)
>> qs
>> Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 74, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1081, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 362, in from_db_value
    return connection.ops.parse_raster(value)
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 362, in parse_raster
    return from_pgraster(value)
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/AQM_API-RewsMqZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/pgraster.py", line 57, in from_pgraster
    pixeltype = POSTGIS_TO_GDAL[pixeltype]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My hope was that using the above code would return a value "qs.rast = 34.1". Could anyone shed any light on this?

The query I am trying to replicate from PostGIS is:

```
#select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-3.43, 52.946),4326) as loc, 

ST_Value(Brt2.rast,1,  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-3.43, 52.946),4326)) as pix_val from Brt2
WHERE ST_Intersects(Brt2.rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-3.43, 52.946),4326))
```

I've come up with the following solution as:

```
qs = Brt2.objects.raw('select rid, ST_Value(brt2.rast,1,  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-3.43, 52.946),4326)) as pix_val from brt2 WHERE ST_Intersects(brt2.rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-3.43, 52.946),4326))')

for i in qs:
    print(i.pix_val)
```

This returns the desired value, but as far as I understand, raw sql queries are open to injection attacks, and I am unsure of how to protect against this. Ideally, I would like to use the GeoDjango ORM.

Comment: Hey. Did you happen to find any solution to this?

Comment: I think using `rast__1__contains` is not a good choice for this purpose. It seems that we should use `ST_Value` and not 'ST_Contains`. I searched GeoDjango's ORM, but could not find an equivalent to `ST_Value` in GeoDjango. Here is a question I wrote about this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/370866/144004