# How to get the raster values of a point using Django's ORM (equivalent to ST_Value in PostGIS)?

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango, django

I am working on a `Django` project that uses `Django ORM` to export raster data into `PostGIS` database. Here is the Django model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class RasterWithName(models.Model):
    rast = models.RasterField()
    name = models.TextField()
```

Currently, in the database, I have 3 rows of data. The picture below shows this:

[image]

Then, I go to Django's `shell` using `python manage.py shell`. What should I write (other than `RasterWithName.objects.raw()` in the shell to perform a query on the rasters and get raster values for, let's say, a point with the location of (lat=10, lon=10) in a list ?

I could not find an equivalent for `ST_Value` in `GeoDjango`.

Comment: Did you find any Solution yet?